# Is there any typo in this assignment problem?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I got this problem in my assignment

> Prove that in a nilpotent group periodic elements of coprime order commute

But I am confused by the term *periodic*,can someone help me to know whether it is a typo or not?

Comment: Periodic == every element of the group has finite order.

Comment: @DonkeyKong,so periodic just mean every element of group is of finite order?

Comment: @DonkeyKong But that is not the use here. In this context it just means element of finite order.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah, you're correct. Sort of a weird sentence, or maybe it's just too early for me. In any case, not a typo!

Comment: @DonkeyKong That seems to be a _periodic group_, not a _periodic element_.

Comment: I know the result that" in a nilpotent group element of coprime order commute".

Comment: periodic element = finite order element; statement is *Prove that in a nilpotent group, the periodic elements of co-prime order commute*.

Comment: @Groups,since we are saying that their order are coprime then what is the point to say they are of finite order(i.e.,by addind term periodic) ,since if any one would have order infinite than co-prime does not make any sense.

Comment: @MichaelKotelskiy Because, as you say yourself, if you did not specify that the elements were periodic, then the question would not make sense.  When writing mathematics, you should not omit essential assumptions merely on the grounds that without them what you wrote would not make sense.

Comment: @DerekHolt,Thank you very much to feel me aware of this aspect of mathematics.